# Why My server is not running using the npm run start:prod ? Below is packgae.json file

Tags: node.js

When I try to run in the production mode, then I got the below error:

> ```
> npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
> npm ERR! errno 1
> npm ERR! shop-api@1.0.0 start:prod: `NODE_ENV=production nodemon server.js`
> npm ERR! Exit status 1
> ```

```
{
  "name": "shop-api",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "app.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start:dev": "nodemon server.js",
    "start:prod": "NODE_ENV=production nodemon server.js",
    "debug": "ndb server.js"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "body-parser": "^1.19.0",
    "dotenv": "^8.2.0",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "mongoose": "^5.9.6",
    "morgan": "^1.10.0",
    "ndb": "^1.1.5"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "nodemon": "^2.0.2"
  }
}
```

Comment: What happens if you just run `node server.js`?

Comment: what OS are you using?

Comment: If `start:dev` is working fine and `start:prod` is not, then clearly there's a problem with the `server.js` file (or something imported there) which depends on the condition `if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production')` (or similar)

Comment: There is no error in server.js file.After adding "start:prod": "SET NODE_ENV=production && nodemon server.js" in package.json instead of "start:prod": "NODE_ENV=production nodemon server.js", My code is running well

Answer (score 2):

I ran into the same problem. 
Just do this:

```
"start": "nodemon server.js",
"start:prod": "NODE_ENV=production npm start"
```

Comment: Please properly format code, [click here to learn how](https://wordpress.com/support/markdown-quick-reference/).

Comment: i changed     "start:prod": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production node server", by     "start:prod": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production npm start" and it works fine for me, thanks Hemant

Answer (score 1):

After adding "start:prod": **"SET NODE_ENV=production && nodemon server.js"** in package.json instead of **"start:prod": "NODE_ENV=production nodemon server.js"**.Then my code is running

Answer (score 1):

I ran into same issue.
this will solve it for you

```
"start:prod": "SET NODE_ENV=production && nodemon server.js"
```

Comment: npm run start:prod in your terminal to run your code

Answer (score 0):

I experience the same problem, just run this command

//=> npm start prod     this work for me 100%

here is my package.json file

```
"start": "nodemon server.js",
"start:prod": "NODE_ENV=production nodemon server.js",
```